# New Teams Windows Firewall Rules

Tags: windows, firewall, microsoft-teams, intune

I genuinely think I'm going crazy with this, does anybody know how to allow any version of the new Microsoft Teams through the Windows Firewall.

If it installs an update, a new location within "Program Files\WindowsApps\MSTeams_%%%%" is added, once you receive a call, you're prompted (if on a Domain network in my instance) to apply admin creds to allow the rule through.

This seems bonkers to me, I've messed around with PowerShell and have various ways of applying these rules, but it still requires a trigger to do so. If a user updates whilst working, it's very likely that they will then be prompted with this.

Am I completely missing something here, or is there a way to allow any version of the New Teams through Windows Firewall? It doesn't look like you can wildcard program paths.

Comment: Are you looking for inbound or outbound rules? Why is a rule required for outbound?

Comment: How was it initially deployed? The `Teams Machine-Wide Installer` package creates inbound rules named `Microsoft Teams (work or school)` and updates them automatically for example.

Comment: Yes the Machine-Wide Installer, the rules get added but prompt if updated to the new version. Any user without admin creds will then have the rules added as block rules.

Comment: And this is *New* Teams, right? I ask because there is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-clients) with Classic Teams, but doesn't seem common to New. You may be able to just use a package filter rule, like: In the firewall gui > create new blank rule > open the properties > Programs and Services > Application Packages > Settings > Apply to this application package: `MSTeams_[short-id]`. That ID doesn't have a version in it, so it may not change. The powershell version is `Set-NetFirewallApplicationFilter -Package [long-id]`

Comment: Hey @Cpt.Whale yes it's the new Teams. I've added the FamilyPackageName through Intune but still doesn't work. I can't understand how this is a thing, it's making me think I'm missing something but I can't see how? Any furhter ideas?

Comment: I was able to hunt down a machine with a slightly different/older version of Teams, and verified that Teams is updating the firewall rule path automatically in my environment. It may be choking on something for you, but it'll be hard to tell on what without digging into its logs or contacting support. I'm not as familiar with intune, but I know there are different ways to manage how local rules are merged with active policy

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I can't understand it, I'm going to try and remove the old version, whether that's referencing anything I'm not sure. But yeah the Teams Wide Installer is already installed on the devices l, whether that is forcing the block rule through maybe? So to confirm in your tests, the Local Merge was set to Yes, were there Teams rules already added into the inbound rules when you looked? And when you updated it added new rules automatically with no prompt? Cheers